# How can i manage a global variable among different webpages in wix?

Tags: variables, global, velo

I am developing a site for online test series. I receive details o student on one page and wish to display the info on net page as dashboard. I need a global variables that can hold the detail of student like his roll no, name, email, class, semester, subject and the test he wishes to solve.
I have tries using a separate .js file to hold variables. However, the values of variables get lost as i move to next page.
can anyone help?
The code and links are attached.

https://ishuuw.wixsite.com/ymatutor/test-series

```
//import wixData from 'wix-data';
import {globalVars} from 'public/vars.js';


$w.onReady(function () {

});


export function button2_click(onClick,button2){
globalVars.StudentRoll=$w('#input1').value
globalVars.StudentName=$w('#input5').value
globalVars.StudentSurname=$w('#input6').value
globalVars.StudentMail=$w('#input7').value


globalVars.StudentClass=$w('#dropdown1').value
globalVars.StudentYear=$w('#dropdown2').value
globalVars.StudentSemester=$w('#dropdown3').value
globalVars.StudentPaper=$w('#dropdown5').value
globalVars.StudentTest=$w('#dropdown6').value


//Just to test, this works well
$w('#text63').text=globalVars.StudentRoll
$w('#text64').text=globalVars.StudentName
$w('#text65').text=globalVars.StudentSurname
$w('#text66').text=globalVars.StudentMail
$w('#text67').text=globalVars.StudentClass
$w('#text68').text=globalVars.StudentYear
$w('#text69').text=globalVars.StudentSemester
$w('#text70').text=globalVars.StudentPaper
$w('#text71').text=globalVars.StudentTest




  }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should be using [wix-storage](https://www.wix.com/code/reference/wix-storage.html). That will allow you to pass information between pages.

Use local storage if you want the data to persist for the user even after the user ends the session. Meaning, next session, the user's data will still be available.

Use session storage if you want the data to be removed when the user's session ends.